# Dismiss progress dialog when no network connection

Tags: android

I am trying to show up a progress dialog when user is signing in.(the app connects to an online mysqldatabase).
I turned off my network connection but the progress dialog is not dismissed.

**How to dismiss the progress dialog if there's no internet connection?**

```
public class BackgroundLogin extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
Context ctx;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
BackgroundLogin(Context ctx)
{
    this.ctx=ctx;
}


@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please Wait..");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Signing in..");
    progressDialog.setMax(5);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
    progressDialog.show();

}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    try {

        if (result.equals("interdit")) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Access forbidden", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else

        if (result.equals("invalid")) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(ctx, "Invalid username or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else

        {
           progressDialog.dismiss();
            Intent i = new Intent(ctx, HomeScreen.class);
            i.putExtra("username", result);


            ctx.startActivity(i);

        }


    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


    String reg_url="http://www.androidiut20.netai.net/verification.php";
    String username=params[0];
    String password=params[1];
    String langue=params[2];
    String connection=params[3];


        try {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);


            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("langue", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(langue, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String response = "";
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                response += line;


            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return response;

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    return null;


}


}
```

Comment: try removing Thread.sleep(1000) from doInBackground() method...

Comment: call dismmiss dialog in your exception may fix the issue.

Comment: Removing Thread.sleep didn't work

Comment: Why you are calling asynctask if internet is not available, check before executing web service if net is available or not,   for your scenario you need to write dismiss code in each and every exception block

Comment: what if internet connection is interrupted suddenly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

inside doInBackground() catch UnknownHostException...it is a subtype of IOException

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
   try{
      //whatever code
   } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
       if (progressDialog.isShowing()) progressDialog.dismiss();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thanks tsiro i tried progressdialog.dismiss() on NullPointerException catch..and it worked

Comment: All answers worked perfectly but i can t accept only one answer.
by the way i can t vote for my low reputation

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground check for the availability of the internet connection like this

```
     if(!isNetworkAvailable()){
       progressDialog.dismiss();
       }
```

Below is the method

```
  public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(final Context context) {
    boolean isNetAvailable = false;
    if (context != null) {
        final ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (mConnectivityManager != null) {
            final NetworkInfo activeNetwork = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if(activeNetwork != null) isNetAvailable = true;
        }
    }
    return isNetAvailable;
}
```

Comment: Cannot resolve method getSystemService..i dont know why this error showed up .I tried this method in another activity no error is showed

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro it worked on NullPointerException and the progress dialog disappeared !!

Answer (score 0):

**Check internet before start the AsyncTask**

take in class isInternetConnection boolean

```
  public static boolean isInternetConnection(Context mContext) 
{
    final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    final NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    final NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);

    if (wifi.isAvailable()&& wifi.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
    {


        return true;
    }
    else if (mobile.isAvailable()&& mobile.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) 
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

**check Internet**

```
if(isInternetConnection(Youractivity.this)
{
     new BackgroundLogin().execute();
}
```

Comment: Awesome bro Er.Arjun saini,Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

In doInBackground() method just add the following logic.

```html
    if(network is not available){
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           if(dialog != null){
           dialog.dismiss();   
          }
     }
});

}
```